# Access a file from File Manager in Android 4.4 shows Exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file, file-manager

I am developing an android application,in this app I am accessing a file from android's default `file manger`.If I run this app in lower versions(Except Android 4.4) I can access file into my application but if I runned my app with `android 4.4` kitkat OS I couldn't access a file from file manager it showed some `Exceptions`. here I attached my LogCat output.

**LogCat**

```
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/etc/vold.fstab: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:158)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:138)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.StorageOptions.readVoldFile(StorageOptions.java:81)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.StorageOptions.determineStorageOptions(StorageOptions.java:21)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.FileChooserActivity.onCreate(FileChooserActivity.java:348)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at com.wepanow.MyFileChooserActivity.onCreate(MyFileChooserActivity.java:24)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
06-03 15:59:34.127 W/System.err(14882):     ... 21 more



06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882): File select error
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.FileChooserActivity.onActivityResult(FileChooserActivity.java:453)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-03 15:59:39.012 E/wepa    (14882):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 15:59:39.012 D/ChooserActivity(14882): Intent Action: null
06-03 15:59:39.012 I/wepa    (14882): FileChooser > onResume
06-03 15:59:39.012 I/wepa    (14882): FC (onResume)has Extra:false
06-03 15:59:39.012 I/wepa    (14882): FC (onResume)has Extra:false
06-03 15:59:39.022 V/PhoneStatusBar(660): setLightsOn(true)
06-03 15:59:43.826 D/wepa    (14882): File selections canceled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am accessing a file from android's default file manger

Android does not have a file manager.

> if I runned my app with android 4.4 kitkat OS I couldn't access a file from file manager it showed some Exceptions

You do not have read access to `/system/etc/vold.fstab` on this device, apparently. There is no requirement that this file be readable on all devices by ordinary SDK apps, and Android 4.4.x has been progressively tightening the security on access to the filesystem.

Comment: Someone trying to enumerate paths *below* the level of Android APIs should read the /proc/mounts not some configuration file for a daemon which may or may not be used.  But as this appears to be third party code or even a distinct application package, it's unlikely jamal is in a position to fix the issue.

Comment: /system/etc/volds.fstab is not even on my kitkat device. At least not visible in file explorers. /proc/mount is and is shown as 0 bytes. However it can be copied to external memory where it has 1983 bytes and is full of mount paths.